# Turn integers into an array

Tags: php, mysql

Well I'm using the (MySQL: id is int data type)

```
GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids 
Example output = 1,2,3,4,5;
```

and then turn whats returned into an array but it keeps coming back as a blob, I need the integers to be individually split.

```
Array
(
[0] => 1,2,3,4,5
)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: down vote, ambiguous question, please re-edit.

Comment: Why not just return them as an array in the first place, instead of concatenating and then splitting them?

Comment: what about mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: @Mike: probably because `MySQL` does not support array datatype.

Comment: @Mike: also, depending the query, it's the difference of polling for one result vs. hitting the resource over and over (esp. if they just want a list of ids).

Comment: Because I'm ordering by category

Comment: @Quassnoi: Okay, perhaps that was a bit ambiguous. I was trying to determine the reason for concatenating them, rather than returning them as individual rows. I'm not saying that what the OP is doing is wrong. I'm just trying to get some more information.

Comment: Since it's so important to learn terminology so you know how to search for answers to your questions, better descriptions of what you want include "turn a string into an array", "split a string by a separator into an array", "build an array from a string"... if you add "php" and search for any of these things the PHP manual page for `explode` is probably the first result from Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$numbers = explode(',', $numbers[0]);
```